# Sencha Touch 2: tapping Ext.Msg.show that have no buttons

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, message, alert

I want to display the popup message without any buttons.

```
Ext.Msg.show({
   title: '',
   message: 'Some text goes here...',
   buttons : []
});
```

It works fine. How to make it disappeared when you tap on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried for you and i got what you want

```
    Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Title',
        message: 'Some text goes here...',
        itemId : 'showMsg',
        buttons : [],
        listeners:[ 
            {
                element: 'element',
                delegate: '',
                event: 'tap',
                fn: function() {
                    this.hide();
                }
            }]
    });
```