# Sencha Touch 2: Ext.Msg.show and tapping anywhere to hide

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, message, alert

I want to display the popup message without any buttons. The message disappears if you tap on it. The code works fine and was taken from [Sencha Touch 2: tapping Ext.Msg.show that have no buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596316/sencha-touch-2-tapping-ext-msg-show-that-have-no-buttons/17598218), thank you Viswa.

```
   Ext.Msg.show({
        title: 'Title',
        message: 'Some text goes here...',
        itemId : 'showMsg',
        buttons : [],
        listeners:[ 
            {
                element: 'element',
                delegate: '',
                event: 'tap',
                fn: function() {
                    this.hide();
                }
            }]
    });
```

How to make it disappeared when you tap **anywhere on the screen**, not on the popup message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `hideOnMaskTap` config.

```
hideOnMaskTap: true
```