# How to remove or hide OK button in Message Box in Sencha Touch 2?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to remove or hide the OK button of a Message Box in Sencha? If yes, how can I do this? If no, what is the reason why? In the Sencha forums, I read this: [How to hide or remove "OK" button of a Dialog](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?90123-How-to-hide-or-remove-quot-OK-quot-button-of-a-Dialog), but would like to get more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way and it worked for me. May be it works for you too. I kept

```
hidden: true
```

in buttons tag.

```
Ext.Msg.show({ 
title: 'Rate it',
buttons: [{
hidden: true,}]
});
```

or you can try this way:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
    title: 'Title',
    message: 'Some text goes here...',
    itemId : 'showMsg',
    buttons : []
});
```

Above mentioned both way hides the Button as you wanted. When i was surfing SO i got these two link [hide message box when clicked on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17610380/sencha-touch-2-ext-msg-show-and-tapping-anywhere-to-hide) and [tapping message box to hide message box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596316/sencha-touch-2-tapping-ext-msg-show-that-have-no-buttons/17598218).
Thought might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just a though.. how would you close the message box without the ok button? :)

What about using a modal panel:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.ModalPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'modal-panel',

    config: {
        height: '50%',
        width: '50%',
        centered: true,
        modal: true,
        hideOnMaskTap: true
    }
});
```

Then:

```
Ext.Viewport.add({
    xtype: 'modal-panel',
    items: [
        {html: 'message'}
    ]
});
```